# Gnome notifications font size is huge. How to change?

Tags: gnome, notifications

I'm running Pop_OS on a System 76 laptop. It's running Gnome and for some reason after re-installing the OS on a new drive, (the original SSD borked on me) the font in the notifications are HUGE! We're talking 72pt here!

Anyways after a couple hours of looking around the interwebs and poking around the system, I've found nothing!

Possible causes are from installing a Gnome extension that I removed. I've tried removing the extensions I installed. I've also tried adding and re-removing the extensions that I tried. No Luck.

Here is an image of what I'm dealing with. I'd just like to reset the notifications back to default.

[image: Whacked notifications]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnome-tweak-tool`, which should be available in the repositories (or installed already), you can adjust font sizes and scaling, along with some HiDPI scaling options.

There are also a few scaling options in the 'Universal Access/Accessibility' section of the Gnome settings program.

One of those should have the setting you need to adjust.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I played around in here a bunch a while back and nothing seemed to work. I played around in there again just now and I turned off all shell extensions and the notifications returned to a normal size. I think an extension I had wasn't uninstalled correctly and causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.  As noted in the comment above disabling all extensions using `gnome-tweak-tool` (or `gnome-tweaks`) solved the issue. You may need to log out and log back in too for it to take effect. Posting this so its easier for someone to find the same solution.  Still not sure what extension is causing the issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

I tried disabling extensions & logging out (also restarting), but no luck.

Then I discovered an additional option in Settings > Devices > Displays > Scale, which was set to 200%. Possibly it got changed when I connected my external display, and didn't change back when I disconnected it. Changing it back to 100% fixed it.